# Getting "app integrity cannot be verified" error when in developer mode

Tags: ios, iphone, outsystems

I currently have my iPhone (iOS 16.3) in developer mode, but when trying to install an apple device application file that I developed, I am getting the "Unable To Install [app]: This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified". The only other way I know of to rectify this is to get a distribution provisioning profile and submit it on a test flight on the app store, but this is not an app I intend to distribute - it's for my own personal testing purposes. Is there a way to hard-bypass this restriction? I own the phone, I take full responsibility if I break it, especially if I break it with an application that I wrote myself.

Comment: You should register the device here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the IPA with a development profile, an ad-hoc, or a distribution profile? For development, you need a development profile that has your device's UUID enabled on it. You do not need to create a distribution profile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77417140/this-app-cannot-be-installed-because-its-integrity-could-not-be-verified

@Craig is there any work around for this situation