# This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified

Tags: flutter, xcode, app-store, ipa, apple-developer

I am making the signed ipa using manual signin, from distribution certificate and App store distribution provisioning profile. We had one Device already added. When we try to install this ipa from diawi to same iphone device we are getting this error: **This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified**

Note: When we try to make the ipa from ios App development profile then it is working fine.
These options i had added before exporting ipa

[image]

Can you guide me where i am doing wrong

Comment: Most probably you have added the device in a wrong way. try to add it again.